# How to pass AJAX column data which is array to a JS function?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, datatables

I need to pass the data from AJAX datatable column which is an array to a function in JS

This is my script.js

```
    table = $("#table").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "/Object/GetAllDetail",
            data: {  },
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: "json",
            dataSrc: "",

            dataFilter: function (data) {
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                json.recordsTotal = json.TotalCount;
                json.recordsFiltered = json.TotalCount;
                json.data = json.list;
                return JSON.stringify(json); // return JSON string
           },
        },
        "columns": [
        {
            "data": null,
            "className": "checkbox",
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var ACT = '<div class="form-check">';
                ACT += '<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxDatatbl" onclick="Display(' + data.text + ',' + data.ArrayNum + ')"  + ' >';
                ACT += '</div >';
                return ACT;
            }

        }]
    }

    function Display(text, array){
         return text + " : " + array;
    }
```

Supposed that the

```
data.text = "First Row";
data.ArrayNum = [1,3,5];
```

The problem is that the ajax converts the data.ArrayNum to arrays before going to the function like these:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxDatatbl" **onclick="Sum("First Row",1,3,5)"** >
```

So the Display() only reads the Display("First Row",1) not the whole array.

How can I join all the array in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick hack would be wrapping your array with `[]` like

```
 ACT += '<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxDatatbl" onclick="Display(' + data.text + ',[' + data.ArrayNum + '])"  + ' >';
```